# Integer square digit by digit

Tags: java, square

There should be a program, which square every digit of an integer and after that concatenate these temporary numbers into a new integer.
I have written a code, which do the trick regarding to my test cases, but an automated tester gives errors for some random generated input numbers.

```
public class SquareDigit {
  public int squareDigits(int n) {
    int tmp = 0;
    String returnvalue="";

    while(n > 0) {
        tmp = n % 10;
        tmp = tmp * tmp;
        returnvalue = returnvalue + Integer.toString(tmp);
        n /= 10;
    }       
    int result=Integer.parseInt(returnvalue);

    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Issue might be due to Integer Precision, use long or BigInteger

Comment: @Sanjeev guess it´s rather due to an Integeroverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`returnvalue = Integer.toString(tmp) + returnvalue;`

instead of

`returnvalue = returnvalue + Integer.toString(tmp);`

You iterate the digits from back to front so e.g for input `123` the intermediate results should be

- `"9"`
- `"49"`
- `"149"`

but in your code it's

- `"9"`
- `"94"`
- `"941"`

Comment: That is really interesting, because it was working with predefined test values. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use BigInteger.
 A [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) is a class that hold integer with arbitrary precision:

> Immutable arbitrary-precision integers.

Your code become wrong when squaring a number you go over the maximum available range of type `int`. A `long` can solve the problem if you test on a range that is under the `long` range. A `BigInteger` work for any integer number.

---

Code should be something similar to that:

```
public  BigInteger squareDigits(int n) {
    BigInteger tmp = null;
    String returnvalue = "";

    while (n > 0) {
        tmp = BigInteger.valueOf(n % 10);
        tmp = tmp.pow(2);
        returnvalue = returnvalue + String.valueOf(tmp);
        n /= 10;
    }       

    return new BigInteger(returnvalue);
  }


  ...

  System.out.println(squareDigits(123456789));  // Print 816449362516941
```

Comment: You need to import java.math.BigInteger;

Comment: I have imported it already, but it is a test environment, so maybe this causes problem with import.

Comment: No there is no problem. You need to import the BigInteger in every class that explicitly use it.

Comment: @KovacsAkos `BigInteger tmp = 0;`, you can´t assign an `int` to a `BigInteger`, use it´s constructor.

Comment: See the updated answer. You will see how to construct a BigInteger and how to make the square.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO : I see, but it also doesn't work. This test system allows only elementary functions.

Comment: Problem is maybe another thing, because error message for my original code: expected:<9414> but was:<4149> It is rather than a logical problem.

Comment: Post your tests and expected results.